# Как скомпилировать драйвер rtl8188eu для OrangePi&

Tags: linux, wifi, orange-pi

На gihub нашел драйвер. Ссылка: https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu
Он правда рассчитан для RasberiPi, но архитектура процессоров что у OrangePi что у RasberiPi одинаковы поэтому я решил попробовать. Затем склонировал файлы и попробовал скомпилировать

`make all`

И получил ошибку

```
make[1]:*** /lib/modules/5.10.43/build: No such file or directory. Stop
make[]: *** [Makefile:155:  module] Error 2
```

Подскажите как исправить ошибку и есть ли драйвер именно под OrangePi

Comment: 1) Наверное логичный вопрос — этот самый `/lib/modules/5.10.43/build` вообще существует? 2) Какая операционная система хоть?

Comment: @andreymal операционка ubunty и build нету.(

Comment: Ubuntu не использует такой способ именования ядер. Ищите, откуда у вас взялось ядро, и скачивайте headers к нему самостоятельно, видимо

Comment: Я нашел утилиту(точно не знаю как назвать) на github: https://github.com/orangepi-xunlong/orangepi-build. Там есть крип для компиляции ядра. Но он компилируется только на архитектуре  x84/64. Я не пойму. Как не создать build скомпилировав ядро на другом пк. И я не могу найти kernak header под версию ядра. При попытки установки он пишет что под мою версию ядра ее нет. Версия ядра 5.18.5-rk3399.

Comment: у драйвера есть dkms обработчик. собери деб пакет